# Vaadin passing data to View

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I have this Navigation bar:

[image]

When clicking request button, this piece of code is executed:

```
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(viewName)
```

How I can pass Select1 and Select2 data to another controller or view when navigateTo is executed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass then to the navigator like this:

```
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(viewName + '/' + value1 + '/' + value2);
```

This will appear in the URL like this http://website.com/application#!viewname/value1/value2

You can get the values in your new view like this. You will need to expand this code to cope with no paramaters. Also since users can change the URL easily you'll need to validate that values are acceptable too.

```
@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {


    String args[] = event.getParameters().split("/");
    String value1 = args[0];
    String value2 = args[1];
```

Comment: Can I pass objects between views ?

Comment: Not directly. You can store objects in the VaadinSession through

Answer (score -3):

You need to use URI fragments. Here are official links:

[Managing URI Fragments](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-urifu.html)

[Using parameters with views](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+parameters+with+views)

and, example code:

```
getUI().getPage().setUriFragment("value1,value2");
```

[image]

Comment: The OP is using a navigator, setting the URI fragment would cause problems.